# Setting a gradient's angle in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I want to create a curl effect on page. I am not able to align gradient with my curl. Please check the attached screenshot to see the settings.

[image]

In the curl see the white line of gradient its on angle around 135°, I want this angle to be like 45°.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is relatively simple and works with most tools.

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while drawing the gradient. It'll lock the angles to multiples of 45°.

If you want other angles, check the *Info* window, which will show your current angle when drawing:

[image]